# How to replace while proxying query in Angular?

Tags: angular, proxy

I have read many links to Angular proxy documentation. But there is no information how can i achieve this rewriting:

```js
http://localhost:4200/xxx/api/objects/ObjectName/file/ObjectName.xml

to

http://localhost:4400/ObjectName.xml
```

ObjectName could be [var1, var2, var3, ...], so i cannot rewrite basepath to file since it could be different. In Nginx you could just write a regexp capturing filename to a names group with **(?<groupName>[^/]*)** and substitute it later using **$groupName**.

How to do same in Angular Proxy conf ?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? => https://angular.io/guide/build#rewrite-the-url-path

Comment: no, you obviously have not read my question and information provided in link

Comment: And by the way, if you DID read ANY of information in that link, you would've seen that it is based on Webpack: So you were looking for your answer on the surface, instead of deepdiving in webpack configuration